# Xamarin.Mac project in a Xamarin.Forms (Portable) solution

Tags: c#, ios, macos, xamarin.forms, xamarin.mac

I'm setting up a new Xamarin.Forms (Portable) solution in Visual Studio 2015. The goal is to deploy the application on Windows, OSX, iOS and Android. So far, in the solution I see the projects XamarinApp (Portable), XamarinApp.Droid, XamarinApp.iOS and XamarinApp.UWP.

Is there a way to add a XamarinApp.Mac project to the solution Xamarin.Forms solution?
Or do all Xamarin.Mac projects have to be developed on a mac using Xamarin Studio/Visual Studio for Mac, as I see standalone projects being created using this method. And if this is the case, is there a way to share the codebase from the project created on my PC that is already targeting Android, UWP and iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xamarin.Forms support for macOS as a target platform is presently [in development](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin.forms/tree/macOS). Per our [roadmap](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/85747/xamarin-forms-feature-roadmap/) it should be expected some time around May. You will ultimately still need a Mac for developing for the platform.

Comment: Excellent, I wasn't aware that there was a public roadmap, this is extremely helpful.

Comment: are we able to use Xamarin.Forms in Xamarin.Mac applications right now if we build that repo ?